# На скриншот, через selenium py не попадает select control

Tags: python, selenium, centos7

Автоматизирую тестирование веб гуя. Требуется скриншоты со всеми окнами.
Проблема заключается вот в чем. При использовании метода save_screenshot, на скриншоты не попадают элементы select control.
Как как побороть эту проблему?

Использую такую функциию. def save_screenshot(driver, filename, dir=[]): screen_home = '' if os.environ.has_key('SCREENSHOT_HOME'): screen_home = os.environ['SCREENSHOT_HOME'] + '/' reletive_path = '/'.join(dir) fullpath = screen_home + reletive_path if not os.path.isdir(fullpath): os.makedirs(fullpath) driver.save_screenshot(fullpath + '/' + filename) окно увы не могу предоставить, но обычная всплывашка.

from PIL import ImageGrab использовать не могу Centos...

Comment: Я конечно не экстрасенс, но было бы неплохо увидеть код, увидеть скриншоты которые вам нужны (сделанные вручную) и увидеть скриншоты которые делаются .save_screenshot

Comment: Использую такую функциию.

def save_screenshot(driver, filename, dir=[]):
    screen_home = ''
    if os.environ.has_key('SCREENSHOT_HOME'):
        screen_home = os.environ['SCREENSHOT_HOME'] + '/'
    reletive_path = '/'.join(dir)
    fullpath = screen_home + reletive_path
    if not os.path.isdir(fullpath):
        os.makedirs(fullpath)
    driver.save_screenshot(fullpath + '/' + filename)

окно увы не могу предоставить, но обычная всплывашка.

Comment: Дополните этим кодом свой вопрос)) не нужно было его писать в комментарии

Comment: И под combo_box вы имеете ввиду выпадающий список?

Comment: Да. Именного его я имею ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ.

Устанавливаем ImageMagick (для Centos нормовар):
sudo yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

Устанавливаем библиотеки:
pip install pillow
pip install pyscreenshot

Используем функцию:
def test(folder_and_name):
    x = pyscreenshot.grab()
    x.save(folder_and_name)

Comment: Ваш метод будет работать если браузер будет headless? я хотел вам написать ответ в виде позиционирования курсора, но вероятно ваш ответ вам подходит и это хорошо)

Comment: Я предполагал, что проблема в том, что не получается навести курсор на всплывающее меню, что-бы его зафиксировать, не так?

Comment: Без графического интерфейса увы ни как. Идет использование сторонней скриншотилки.

Comment: Курсор без проблем наводился и фиксация элемента нормально происходила. Затык был в том, что это объект select. Как он появляется и можно ли к нему подключится - не понятно...